# Difference between Python Interpreter and IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x

For homework in my basic python class, we have to start python interpreter in interactive mode and type a statement. Then, we have to open IDLE and type a statement. I understand how to write statements in both, but can't quite tell them apart? I see that there are to different desktop apps for python, one being the python 3.7 (32-bit), and the other being IDLE. Which one is the interpreter, and how do I get it in interactive mode? Also, when I do open IDLE do I put my statement directly in IDLE or, do I open a 'new file' and do it like that? I'm just a bit confused about the differences between them all. But I do really want to learn this language! Please help!

Comment: do you mean [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)?

Comment: @KevinHe [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/idle.html) or Integrated Development and Learning Environment. It's a thing.

Comment: @Engineero cool. noted

Comment: Interactive mode is when you type a statement, press Enter, and see the result. It seems you are already doing that. A Python interpreter is a program which reads what you have typed and gives you back the result. IDLE also contains an interpreter, but it has some more features, like a built-in source code editor.

Comment: @mkrieger1 is IDLE considered Python's interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python unlike some languages can be written one line at a time with you getting feedback after every line . This is called interactive mode. You will know you are in interactive mode if you see ">>>" on the far left side of the window. This mode is really only useful for doing small tasks you don't think will come up again.

Most developers write a whole program at once then save it with a name that ends in ".py" and run it in an interpreter to get the results.

Comment: So is IDLE considered python's interpreter? And thanks for your answer!

Comment: No IDLE is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) which just means it's easy to write and run a program in it than if you were to do it with a traditional text editor like Notepad. The Python interpreter is simply called "the Python interpreter" every scripting language has it's own interpreter so you just refer to it by the the language's name. Please press the top arrow and the check mark to my answer if it answered your question.